# Access Spring beans from a Junit Suite

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit4

I want to accomplish this - Run a background process (a Solr instance actually)  that all the tests in my JUnit Suite will use.

To do this - Created a JUnit class annotated with `@RunWith(Suites.class)`. And added a `ClassRule` on the Suite to start the server and stop it. Individual tests in the suite were annotated with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` and `@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)`. And I also require access to some of the Beans in the Suite itself (like a spring managed settings bean). What's the best way to do this. What I tried.

1. Annotated individual tests with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`
2. Had the Suite create an `ApplicationContext` via
   `SpringApplication.run` and access any bean that it wants (a spring
   managed Settings bean for example and use it one of ClassRules of
   this Suite).

What I observed is that the `ApplicationContext` context gets created everytime, One for the Suite because I called `SpringApplication.run` and one for every test. I obviously want to avoid this and caching of the `ApplicationContext` between test runs also does not seem to work in this case.

So what are the best practices to handle this case.
Any suggestions/recommendations will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Spring folks : any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

This is a long forgotten question, but it shown up on my google search, so I am assuming it still somehow relevant :)

I was going down on the same path but I hit so many road blocks that I decided to change my approach:

1. Create a JUnit runner as described [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_api.htm).
2. Change #1 to inherit `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` here is an [example](http://sysout.be/2010/04/15/extending-spring-junit-runner/).
3. Finally, annotate your Test classes with `@RunWith(MyCustomRunner.class)`

There you go. You can add whatever logic you need inside your runner.